# ctx.fillRect From Vertical Center

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanted to make a canvas element to visualise the audio from a HTML5 audioplayer.

To do this I used the following JS:

```
let start = function () {
  let audio = document.getElementById('audioplayer');
  let ctx = new AudioContext();
  let analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
  let audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  // we have to connect the MediaElementSource with the analyser
  audioSrc.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(ctx.destination);
  // we could configure the analyser: e.g. analyser.fftSize (for further infos read the spec)
  // analyser.fftSize = 64;
  // frequencyBinCount tells you how many values you'll receive from the analyser
  let frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

  // we're ready to receive some data!
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    cwidth = canvas.width,
    cheight = canvas.height - 2,
    meterWidth = 5, //width of the meters in the spectrum
    gap = 2, //gap between meters
    capHeight = 1,
    capStyle = '#fff',
    meterNum = 1200 / (10 + 2), //count of the meters
    capYPositionArray = []; ////store the vertical position of hte caps for the preivous frame
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#92e657');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#92e657');
  gradient.addColorStop(0, '#92e657');

  // loop
  function renderFrame() {
    let array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    let step = Math.round(array.length / meterNum); //sample limited data from the total array
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
    for (let i = 0; i < meterNum; i++) {
      let value = array[i * step];
      if (capYPositionArray.length < Math.round(meterNum)) {
        capYPositionArray.push(value);
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = capStyle;
      //draw the cap, with transition effect
      if (value < capYPositionArray[i]) {
        ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - (--capYPositionArray[i]), meterWidth, capHeight);
      } else {
        ctx.fillRect(i * 12, cheight - value, meterWidth, capHeight);
        capYPositionArray[i] = value;
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient; //set the filllStyle to gradient for a better look
      ctx.fillRect(i * 12 /*meterWidth+gap*/, cheight - value + capHeight, meterWidth, cheight); //the meter
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  }

  renderFrame();
  // audio.play();
};
```

While this does work, the only issue is that the rectangle fills from bottom to top. Is there a way I can get the rectangle to fill from the vertical center instead?

EDIT: I realised I haven't explained the issue clearly enough so am making an update here and I'm adding the following picture below.

[image]

So I want to draw my rectangle from the red part (which is what I was referring as the vertical center) so that when it grows, it increased by an equal amount up and down on the y axis. Is this possible or would I have to have two fillRect commands to do the up and down movement separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Is there a way I can get the rectangle to fill from the vertical center instead?"*

Yes just modify the various [`ctx.fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) calls to draw the rectangles how and where you want.

[`ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) fills a rectangle at `x`, `y` with a `width` and `height`

for example the last `fillRect` becomes

```
ctx.fillRect(ctx.canvas.width / 2, i * 12 , value + 1,  10);
//           |------------------/  |----/   |-------/   |/ 
//           \ center of canvas    |        |           |
//                                 |        \ bar width |
//                                 \ dist from top      |
//                                                      \ bar height
//
```

Also you may want to change the orientation of the gradient eg from `ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300)` to `ctx.createLinearGradient(ctx.canvas.width / 2, 0, ctx.canvas.width, 0)`

Comment: I tried your solution and then realised that I haven't explained the issue well enough.

Comment: I have now updated my original post with more information and a picture that should help illustrate what I'm trying to do.